# How can I download a PDF file from a form using UI designer?? Bonita

Tags: bonita

The thing is I have found how upload a document and after that downolad it. But I just want to download it. I want to do it using the UI designer but I dont know how to do it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know which tool are you using to design your UI, anyway this is concerning functionality, not design. In that point, i need to know wich language do you want (or can) use. For example, in PHP, it's very simple, you can make something like:
(create php file) downloadpdf.php
1st: (if you want to generate pdf "on the fly":

```
<?php
function download($foo){
    content headers (type, force-download, etc)
    database select to get data or harcode it.
    echo data
}
?>
```

and call this function with some id to select from database or something (ignore if you want to hardcode it)

Other option to download a file, if it's stored on server is making a link to this file (statically or dyamically). If you wanna take control to file downloads, check this post:

http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

I don't mean that it can be done with UI designer tools, and it's not concerned if it's from a form or not.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you a lot! Im using Bonitasoft that use BPM. +1 :)

Comment: hope it was helpful, mark the answer as solved and upvote to next visitors can find the solution easily

Answer (score 0):

You should create link and variable which type is javascript expression. On Variable value write

```
return "/bonita/portal/" + $data.context.mainDoc_ref.url;
```

On link URL write your variable and to text

```
Download: {{context.mainDoc_ref.fileName}}
```

[Here you can find excellent example for this case](https://github.com/Bonitasoft-Community/parent-child-shared-document/releases/tag/7.2.2-1.1.0)